# How to extract information about the exact type of object that is the target of injection from IContext in Ninject?

Tags: c#, ninject

In my application there is a necessity to create implementations of the interface that depend on the type of the object they are used in. To do that i decided to implemnt a descendant of a SimpleProvider that in terms of classic Ninject example should go like:

```
public class MyProvider: Provider<IWeapon>
{
    protected override IWeaponCreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        //if the weapon user is of type samurai
        {
             return new Katana();
        }
        //if the weapon user implements IHorseman
        {
             return Kernel.Get<IHorsemanWeapon>();
        }
        return new Sword;
    }
}
```

In my specific case i want to use LogManager.GetLogger(type.FullName).
The problem for me is lack of comprehensive description of IContext or my inability to find it - and so i do not know how to get the type from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the target of the injection with `IContext.Request.Target`:

```
public class MyProvider: Provider<IWeapon>
{
    protected override IWeaponCreateInstance(IContext context)
    {
        if (context.Request.Target.Type == typeof(Samurai))
        {
             return new Katana();
        }
        if (typeof(IHorseman).IsAssignableFrom(context.Request.Target.Type))
        {
             return Kernel.Get<IHorsemanWeapon>();
        }
        return new Sword;
    }
}
```

You can read more about [Contextual bindings](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding).

Comment: You have my sincere gratitude. This is exactly what i needed.